# How specify the folder for the test assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, nunit

I have a project on ASP.NET MVC3.  I have written unit tests using NUnit, but their work need a certain folder. I was told that the path to the folder for the test assembly must be specified in the web.config or app.config. Can anyone help point out where exactly this way?)

Comment: please tell us which testing framework you use, maybe you do not even need to specify the folder in web.config, but in settings.

Comment: I use NUnit testing framework :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using nUnit, there is no need to define the working directory in the web.config,but in the settings. given the case you have your own "Testing Project" you can run separately, i'd highly recommend doing hte following:

> go to: Project -> Settings -> Debug
>   check: "Start External Program" and reference the nUnit TestRunner or GUI (you will find it in your installation directory)
>   As command line argument specify the dll your project gets compiled to. (sth like: MyProject.dll)
>   As Working Directory you must specify the `bin/{config}/` folder of your project.

this folder might be something like: `C:\Users\Geray Sunov\Projects\MyProject\bin\Debug\`

if you now debug your testing project, nUnit testrunner should open and you just have to click "run Tests"

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which unit test framework you are using. If you are using MSTest you could use the TestContext property to get the current working directory in which the test executes:

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeTests
{
    public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ATest()
    {
        string currentDirectory = TestContext.DeploymentDirectory;
        ...
    }
}
```

If you wanted to have an initial set of files deployed in some location you could use the [`[DeploymentItem]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: you completely missed the OP's point. he asks for where he has to specify that TestContext.Path

Answer (score 0):

In your app.config file define a section like so

```
    <appSettings>
       <add key="TestPath" value="Insert your path here..."/>
    </appSettings>
```

Then you can access this in your code by

```
string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TestPath"].ToString();
```